# Where can I find shapefiles of US county or city neighborhoods?

Tags: geospatial, usa

When I search for a neighborhood in Google I usually get a preview of that neighborhood on Google Maps in my search results. My question is...  where do they get this data?

If it's city / county dependent then is there a good rule of thumb for finding this data?

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neighborhood data can be downloaded from here:

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/neighborhoods-us-2017-zillow-segs

[Stack Overflow: Where can I find a city/neighborhood database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557720/569976) has good info as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can get shapefiles by county, ZIP code and census block from the US Census Bureau.

https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php

I'm not sure if this is the same data that Google uses.